# Wordpress error - PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type_from_metadata()

Tags: plugins, themes, errors, updates, fatal-error

I'm working on a website that has been met with the WordPress "white screen of death" error, 'The site is experiencing technical difficulties.'

I believe this occurred when updating all plugins, I have tried disabling all plugins of the website (by renaming the `/wp-content/plugins` to `/wp-content/plugins.hold`), but that did not work. I did the same with disabling the used theme but got the same result.

So after enabling debugging and looking through the debug.log, I have found this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type_from_metadata() in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php:119

I am not sure what is causing this and I would really appreciate any help in this.

Here's the full log.

```
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:36 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Roots_Vcard_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4503
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:37 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Roots_Vcard_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4503
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type_from_metadata() in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): register_block_core_archives('')
#1 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-settings.php(525): do_action('init')
#4 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-config.php(114): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#5 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#6 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-cron.php(39): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php on line 119
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type_from_metadata() in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): register_block_core_archives('')
#1 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-settings.php(525): do_action('init')
#4 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-config.php(114): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#5 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#6 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#7 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/index.php(17): require('/home/uni19047/...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php on line 119
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-content/advanced-cache.php on line 22
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:45 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Roots_Vcard_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4503
[28-Sep-2020 16:34:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type_from_metadata() in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): register_block_core_archives('')
#1 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-settings.php(525): do_action('init')
#4 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-config.php(114): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#5 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#6 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/uni19047/...')
#7 /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/index.php(17): require('/home/uni19047/...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /home/uni19047/public_html/udu.com.au/wp-includes/blocks/archives.php on line 119
```

And I am using cPanel for this.

Please do give me some guidance on how to fix this, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to my mind is that You should check Your wp-settings.php file, as it should include wp-includes/blocks.php file where "register_block_type_from_metadata" function is defined

check that file for this line of code:

`require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/blocks.php';`

if its not there, then Your wordpress installation could have been either hacked or interupted while updating

As We find Out, register_block_type_from_metadata function definition was missing in blocks.php file, due to wordpress update interuption. Replacing that file with the original version fixes the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! But yes there is that code in the wp-settings.php file. It appears as `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/blocks.php' );`

Comment: What about "register_block_type_from_metadata" function in wp-includes/blocks.php file?

Comment: Yes, there is no function for that in wp-includes/blocks.php. I guess that is the issue? This is the closest thing;
```function register_block_type( $name, $args = array() ) {
 return WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->register( $name, $args );
}```

Comment: there should be function named exactly "register_block_type_from_metadata"

Comment: There is no function named that, is this is the issue then? Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Quick fix would be replace that file with the new one ( download the new wordpress installation package [with right wp_version] and search for and replace that file

Comment: Better fix would be reinstall wordpress, and the best fix would be scan for malware, find whats going on on Your site, and reinstall wordpress

Comment: Thank you so much Andrzej! It's all working now, it was just that blocks.php file, there were a few hundred lines of code missing from it. I now have access to the site and the Wordpress dashboard where it says that an automatic update was interrupted, so I'm guessing that was the issue and caused blocks.php to be incomplete. If you could type this up into a separate answer I will mark it as a solution (or I could just do that if that makes more sense?). Thanks a lot! I will look into that as well.

Comment: I edited the answer :) Keep in mind that there could be more corrupted files